# How to allow only one / in regex

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml

I have an regex looking like this `"[a-æøåA-ÆØÅ0-9-/().\s]{1,100}$"`. I would like to allow ONE `/` in user input from textbox, e.g. like `"3/4 inch fitting bla bla"`.
How can I do that in a safe way, and is it safe at all?
My query look something like this.

```
XmlElement bemærkning = xmldoc.CreateElement("Bemærkning");
bemærkning.InnerText = txtBemærkningWT.Text;

//XmlElement usernamePCxml = xmldoc.CreateElement("UsernamepcXML");
//usernamePCxml.InnerText = usernamePC.ToString();

parentelement.AppendChild(type);
parentelement.AppendChild(art);
parentelement.AppendChild(l);
parentelement.AppendChild(bemærkning);
parentelement.AppendChild(varenummer);
parentelement.AppendChild(opretter);
parentelement.AppendChild(date);

//parentelement.AppendChild(usernamePCxml);

xmldoc.DocumentElement.AppendChild(parentelement);
xmldoc.Save(Server.MapPath(map));
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you also check the total number of characters `{1,100}` there is no simple solution (that I can think of) for one regex. The easyest way is probably to do a separate check either for the occurence of `/` or for the overall length. If you check the total length separately you could use a regex like this:

```
"^[a-æøåA-ÆØÅ0-9-().\s]*\/?[a-æøåA-ÆØÅ0-9-().\s]*$"
```

Notice that I added a ^ at the beginnin to indicate the start of the input. I don'nt know if this is necessary in your case but it probably is.

Regarding the safity: you are using `InnerText`, which escapes markup that might be contained in the input, `InnerXml` does not. So you should be fine.